# Navbar com scroll usando SemanticUI

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Preciso fazer uma navbar fixed top. Quando o usuário rolar a página a navbar deve se manter no topo porém num tamanho menor, exibindo apenas os ícones e omitindo os textos.
Necessito que seja realizado no SemanticUI pois é a especificação do sistema.
Baseando em alguns exemplos obtidos na internet, consegui apenas fixar no topo, mas redimensionar e omitir os textos ainda não.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui borderless main menu">
<div href="#" class="header item" id="logo">
    <img class="ui short circular image" src="assets/images/logo.png">
</div>
<div class="ui text container">
    <a class="item" title='Usu&aacute;rios'>
        <i class="large users icon"></i><span class='large screen only six wide column'>Usu&aacute;rios</span></a>
    <a class="item" title='Distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o Autom&aacute;tica'>
        <i class="large settings icon disabled"></i><span class='large screen only six wide column'>Distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o Autom&aacute;tica</span></a>
    <a class="item" title='Relat&oacuterios'>
        <i class="line chart icon"></i><span class='large screen only six wide column'>Relat&oacuterios</span></a>
     <a class="item" title='Pesquisar'>
        <i class="large search icon disabled"></i><span class='large screen only six wide column'>Pesquisar</span></a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
   body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.main.container {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.main.menu {
    margin-top: 4em;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition:
            box-shadow 0.5s ease,
            padding 0.5s ease
;
}
.main.menu .item img.logo {
    margin-right: 4.5em;
}

.overlay {
    float: left;
    margin: 0em 3em 1em 0em;
}
.overlay .menu {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

.main.menu.fixed {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.overlay.fixed .menu {
    left: 800px;
}
.ui.borderless.main.menu {
    background-color: #3d698e;

}

.ui.menu .item{
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-left: 4em;
}

.ui.footer.segment {
    margin: 5em 0em 0em;
    padding: 5em 0em;
}

#logo{
    padding-left: 10em;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(document)
    .ready(function() {

        // fix main menu to page on passing
        $('.main.menu').visibility({
            type: 'fixed'
        });
        $('.overlay').visibility({
            type: 'fixed',
            offset: 80
        });

        // lazy load images
        $('.image').visibility({
            type: 'image',
            transition: 'vertical flip in',
            duration: 300
        });

        // show dropdown on hover
        $('.main.menu  .ui.dropdown').dropdown({
            on: 'hover'
        });
    })
;
```

Foto:

[image: Antes do Scroll]

Após o scroll o menu deve ficar igual desse site http://pt.stackoverflow.com.
Com uma altura pequena mas exibindo apenas os ícones e o logo pequenos`.

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço esse framework, mas talvez seja de ajuda esse exemplo em jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var alturaInicial = 200; // Valores de Exemplo
    var alturaReduzida = 75;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > alturaInicial) {          
        $(".main.menu").css({"height":alturaReduzida + "px"});
        $(".text-itens").hide();
        $("#logo").css({"width":"25%"});
    } else {
        $(".main.menu").css({"height":alturaInicial + "px"});
        $(".text-itens").show();
        $("#logo").css({"width":"100%"});
    }
});
```